# How to use brace expansion with newline

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

I tried this method, but it shows an unwanted space at the beginning of new lines:

```
$ echo -e {1..5}"\n"  
1  
 2  
 3  
 4  
 5
```

Comment: A workaround: `printf -v a "%s\n" {1..5}; echo -n "$a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion creates a *space-separated* list of strings. In your example, this means you get `1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n 5\n`, which explains the space after each newline.

To gain more control about the output format, you could use a loop:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: I am able to solve this problem via for loop and also by `]$  echo -e {1,"\n"{2..5}}`  But why `$ echo -e {1..5}"\n" ` not work

Comment: With `echo -e {1,"\n"{2..5}}`, you get `1 \n2 \n3 \n4 \n5`. Note that now the spaces are after the number and *before* the newline. They didn't go away, they just are not visible.

Comment: But how to remove space ?

Comment: As I said in the answer already, a brace expansion creates a list of strings that are *separated with spaces*. If you don't want spaces in your output, you cannot use the output of a brace expansion directly. The `for` loop is a possible solution, because it splits up the output and removes the spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to output a list of numbers, `seq` is a dedicated tool-

```
$ seq 1 5 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Staying as close as possible to your original question, you could just pipe to sed. This simply gets rid of those 'unwanted spaces'.

```
echo -e {1..5}'\n' | sed 's/ //g'
```

General syntax for sed in this case: `sed 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'` where 's' = substitute and '/' = delimeter

Answer (score 1):

Just put a backspace before the opening brace, like this:
`echo - e \\b{1..5}\\n`

Comment: can you please explain what that does?

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output to `tr` to simply transform the spaces into a newline:

```sh
$ echo {1..5} | tr ' ' '\n'
1
2
3
4
5
```